# my webService doesn't return a correct response for SOAP because of a lazy initialize exception

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-data, glassfish

I have a web service which run, and i can read my wsdl on the right url.
I also have my service, model and consumer which work because when i send i request with debug mode, i see the result from my DB.
But, when my WebMethod return the result, i just have an empty response and an error in glassfish log which say : 
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: p3.model.book.Book.borrowing, could not initialize proxy - no Session

i thaught it was the lazy loading of my borrowing but it seems not to be that.

> [2019-01-31T12:53:50.804+0100] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [com.sun.xml.ws.servlet.http] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1548935630804] [levelValue: 1000] [[
>     caught throwable
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: p3.model.book.Book.borrowing, could not initialize proxy - no Session
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:602)
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:217)
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:581)
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148)
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:303)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.iterator(Lister.java:281)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.iterator(Lister.java:268)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:133)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:360)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:69)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:172)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:360)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:69)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:172)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:360)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:276)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.marshal(BridgeImpl.java:104)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.api.Bridge.marshal(Bridge.java:145)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.BridgeWrapper.marshal(BridgeWrapper.java:176)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:415)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:192)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:226)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:144)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:242)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:636)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:108)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$3.onCompletion(HttpAdapter.java:739)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$1.onCompletion(WSEndpointImpl.java:357)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.completionCheck(Fiber.java:927)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.run(Fiber.java:823)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.start(Fiber.java:420)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.processAsync(WSEndpointImpl.java:368)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:398)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.metro.api.config.management.ManagedEndpoint.process(ManagedEndpoint.java:234)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.invokeAsync(HttpAdapter.java:734)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:212)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:81)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:706)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   ]]

My wsdl exposed :

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<!--
 Published by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is Metro/2.4.0 (wsit240-7e98ff4; 2017-08-03T21:19:54+0200) JAXWS-RI/2.3.0 JAXWS-API/2.3.0 JAXB-RI/2.3.0 JAXB-API/2.3.0 svn-revision#unknown. 
-->
<!--
 Generated by JAX-WS RI (http://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws). RI's version is Metro/2.4.0 (wsit240-7e98ff4; 2017-08-03T21:19:54+0200) JAXWS-RI/2.3.0 JAXWS-API/2.3.0 JAXB-RI/2.3.0 JAXB-API/2.3.0 svn-revision#unknown. 
-->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://webService2.p3/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://webService2.p3/" name="workWeb">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://webService2.p3/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/library-webservice/workWs?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="init">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:init"/>
</message>
<message name="initResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:initResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="searchEngineWorkByTitleAndAuthor">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:searchEngineWorkByTitleAndAuthor"/>
</message>
<message name="searchEngineWorkByTitleAndAuthorResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:searchEngineWorkByTitleAndAuthorResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="searchEngineWorkByTitle">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:searchEngineWorkByTitle"/>
</message>
<message name="searchEngineWorkByTitleResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:searchEngineWorkByTitleResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="searchEngineWorkByAuthor">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:searchEngineWorkByAuthor"/>
</message>
<message name="searchEngineWorkByAuthorResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:searchEngineWorkByAuthorResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="workWs">
<operation name="init">
<input wsam:Action="http://webService2.p3/workWs/initRequest" message="tns:init"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://webService2.p3/workWs/initResponse" message="tns:initResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="searchEngineWorkByTitleAndAuthor">
<input wsam:Action="http://webService2.p3/workWs/searchEngineWorkByTitleAndAuthorRequest" message="tns:searchEngineWorkByTitleAndAuthor"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://webService2.p3/workWs/searchEngineWorkByTitleAndAuthorResponse" message="tns:searchEngineWorkByTitleAndAuthorResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="searchEngineWorkByTitle">
<input wsam:Action="http://webService2.p3/workWs/searchEngineWorkByTitleRequest" message="tns:searchEngineWorkByTitle"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://webService2.p3/workWs/searchEngineWorkByTitleResponse" message="tns:searchEngineWorkByTitleResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="searchEngineWorkByAuthor">
<input wsam:Action="http://webService2.p3/workWs/searchEngineWorkByAuthorRequest" message="tns:searchEngineWorkByAuthor"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://webService2.p3/workWs/searchEngineWorkByAuthorResponse" message="tns:searchEngineWorkByAuthorResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="workWsPortBinding" type="tns:workWs">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="init">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="searchEngineWorkByTitleAndAuthor">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="searchEngineWorkByTitle">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="searchEngineWorkByAuthor">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="workWeb">
<port name="workWsPort" binding="tns:workWsPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/library-webservice/workWs"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

my model :

```
package p3.model.book;

import p3.model.borrowing.Borrowing;
import p3.model.work.Work;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@XmlType(name = "Book")
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen_book", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "gen_book", sequenceName = "seq_book", allocationSize = 1)
    Integer id;

    private String referenceCode;

    private boolean isAvailable;

    @ManyToOne
    private Work works;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Borrowing> borrowing;

    public Book(String referenceCode, boolean isAvailable) {
        this.referenceCode = referenceCode;
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
    }

    public Book(String referenceCode, boolean isAvailable, Work works) {
        this.referenceCode = referenceCode;
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
        this.works = works;
    }

    public Book() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getReferenceCode() {
        return referenceCode;
    }

    public void setReferenceCode(String referenceCode) {
        this.referenceCode = referenceCode;
    }

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return isAvailable;
    }

    public void setAvailable(boolean isAvailable) {
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
    }

    public Work getWorks() {
        return works;
    }

    public void setWorks(Work works) {
        this.works = works;
    }

    public List<Borrowing> getBorrowing() {
        return borrowing;
    }

    public void setBorrowing(List<Borrowing> borrowing) {
        this.borrowing = borrowing;
    }
}
```

in my debug mode, i have this trouble and i don't know how to solve it :

[debug before response returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25TV9.png)

Somebody have an idea ?

Thank you to read and help me.

Alexandre.

Comment: *"i thaught it was the lazy loading of my borrowing but it seems not to be that."* The exception message would suggest otherwise.

Comment: Finally, after many try, i find my f....g trouble. It was my model which have annotation OneToMany and ManyToOne and when i asked something, a list was download but i didn't have the good format for SOAP so the client did'nt understand the correct data format. (if i'm not clear, i still post my solution)

Comment: best way to avoid trouble like this is to add @JsonIgnoreProperties on properties ask on each side of the manytoOne or oneToMany

Answer (score 0):

i solved my trouble modifying my model like this : (remove annotation)

```
package p3.model.book;

import p3.model.work.Work;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
//@XmlType(name = "Book")
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen_book", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "gen_book", sequenceName = "seq_book", allocationSize = 1)
    Integer id;

    private String referenceCode;

    private boolean isAvailable;



    public Book(String referenceCode, boolean isAvailable) {
        this.referenceCode = referenceCode;
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
    }

    public Book() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getReferenceCode() {
        return referenceCode;
    }

    public void setReferenceCode(String referenceCode) {
        this.referenceCode = referenceCode;
    }

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return isAvailable;
    }

    public void setAvailable(boolean isAvailable) {
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
    }


}
```